# (.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `printf' nasm

Tags: x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to access and print the elements of arr found in the data section below in nasm using printf from c, but every time I get (.text+0x4e): undefined reference to `printf.
can anyone tell me the problem?

```
xor rcx, rcx
print_array:
    cmp rcx, r8
    jz exit
    mov rax, [arr+rcx]
    inc r8
    push    rax                     ; caller-save register
            push    rsi                     ; caller-save register
            mov     rdi, char_format        ; set 1st parameter (format)
            mov     rsi, r8              ; set 2nd parameter (current_number)
            xor     rax, rax                ; because printf is varargs
            call    printf                  ; printf(format, current_number)
            pop     rsi                     ; restore caller-save register
            pop     rax                     ; restore caller-save register
    jmp print_array

exit:
    mov rax, 0
    pop rbp



section .data
  arr: dd 30, 10, 6, 4, 8, 15, 1, 60, 7, 19, 17, 13, 11
  ent: dd "enter the number of items", 10
  char_format:        db  "%c", 10, 0
  decimal_format:        db  "%d", 10, 0
  string_format:        db  "%s", 10, 0
```

Comment: Is the routine known as 'printf' to C programmers actually labelled as 'printf' in the binary?  It ain't necessarily so; it depends on the compiler system.  Could be _printf, could be something else.  I assumed that you're actually linking with the C library, though you have not explicitly said so.

Comment: in nasm, it's printf

Comment: @another-dave: x86-64 Linux uses `printf`.  We can rule out Windows based on the calling convention.  x86-64 MacOS uses `_printf`, but I'm not sure if it calls the default section `.text`.  So probably the OP just didn't link libc.  Anyway, not a [mcve] without including the build commands, like `gcc nasm-output.o main.c`